# There are no commands defined in the "make:" namespace. When I am trying to create a controller in visual studio code terminal

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I am trying to make a controller in the visual studio code terminal with this command in laravel
php artisan make::controller RegistrationController
Upon entering it shows there are no commands defined in the "make:" namespace.

[image: Image attached below]

Comment: You have a typo. It should be `make:controller`, not `make::controller` (it should be one colon, not two)

Comment: The error is showing you clearly that it is a typo and suggesting the correct command namespace `Do you mean this? make`

Comment: Thank you so much I m a beginner so forgive me for posting little mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your command has an extra : symbol in it. Try

```
php artisan make:controller RegistrationController
```

Comment: I commend you for wanting to help your fellow developers, and you should keep it up! However, when it comes to typo questions, we usually only leave a comment about the issue and then vote to close the question instead of answering it. It's extremely rare that typo questions are helpful for anyone else.

Comment: @M.Eriksson ahh.....sorry, I am new here, still learning to navigate the site. I will keep it in mind.